# Moviepy's ImageSequenceClip() reads PNGs wrongly like 0, 10, 100 instead of traditional counting

Tags: python, matplotlib, counting, moviepy

So I have this for-loop that creates a photo of each earthquake and names them earthquake0, earthquake1, earthquake2, and so on.

```
plt.savefig("exports\earthquake{0}.png".format(i))
```

To convert these images to GIF, I use this

```
image_list='exports'
my_clip = ImageSequenceClip(image_list, fps=0.75)
my_clip.write_gif('eqph_gif.gif')
```

However, ImageSequenceClip() reads the files like earthquake0.png, earthquake10.png, earthquake100.png. How do I make my code read the photos traditionally like 0, 1, 2, 3, and until the last number which is 187?

Comment: For reference: https://www.reddit.com/r/moviepy/comments/gst40s/imagesequenceclip_reads_pngs_wrongly_like_0_10/